# forwarding from internal to external network does not work

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, forwarding

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server with two NICs. One is connected to the **internal network** (eth0, 192.168.4.0/24) and the other one is connected to a **router with internet access** (eth1, network 192.168.2.0/24).

What I want to achieve is to give the clients of the 192.168.4.0/24 network internet access. So I ran the following commands:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

as far as I understand, the clients should now be able to reach the router, but it doesn't work:

```
$ ping 192.168.2.1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
```

and enabling NAT as a final step doesn't work

```
$ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Can you please tell me where my mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check your routes eg default gateway? Check route -n.

Otherwise you could try setting a rule to route  back the packets from the established connections.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```